# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'articles')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error when I am trying to render elements by mapping over an array name "articles".
< Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'articles')>
Code description:

1. we have a class-based component News.
2. an array of "articles" which I am mapping over and trying to render a new component "NewsItem"
3. I have used setState.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NewsItem from "./NewsItem";

export class News extends Component {
  articles = [
    {
      source: { id: "news24", name: "News24" },
      author: "AFP",
      title:
        "SA great hails 'mind-blowing' England as Proteas eye mammoth test",
      description:
        'South Africa great Mike Procter hopes England\'s "mind-blowing" approach to Test cricket under captain Ben Stokes and coach Brendon McCullum is a sign of things to come.',
      url: "https://www.news24.com/sport/Cricket/Proteas/sa-great-hails-mind-blowing-england-as-proteas-eye-mammoth-test-20220815",
      urlToImage:
        "https://cdn.24.co.za/files/Cms/General/d/2280/908ffc719a2d42ed86d2df3c5007d908.jpg",
      publishedAt: "2022-08-15T07:20:45+00:00",
      content:
        'South Africa great Mike Procter hopes England\'s "mind-blowing" approach to Test cricket under captain Ben Stokes and coach Brendon McCullum is a sign of things to come as they prepare to face his nat… [+2822 chars]',
    },
    {
      source: { id: "bbc-sport", name: "BBC Sport" },
      author: "BBC Sport",
      title: "Shane Warne memorial - watch & follow updates",
      description:
        "Watch live coverage and follow text updates and tributes from the state memorial for Australian cricket legend Shane Warne at the Melbourne Cricket Ground.",
      url: "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/live/cricket/60916236",
      urlToImage:
        "https:////m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-sport-seo-meta/1.22.0/images/bbc-sport-logo.png",
      publishedAt: "2022-03-30T08:22:26.498888Z",
      content:
        "Former England bowler and BBC cricket presenter Isa Guha, who became a colleague of Warne's in the commentary box: \"It has been a strange few weeks - a lot of shock and then we did our own tribute at… [+396 chars]",
    },
    {
      source: { id: "espn-cric-info", name: "ESPN Cric Info" },
      author: null,
      title:
        "PCB hands Umar Akmal three-year ban from all cricket | ESPNcricinfo.com",
      description:
        "Penalty after the batsman pleaded guilty to not reporting corrupt approaches | ESPNcricinfo.com",
      url: "http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/29103103/pcb-hands-umar-akmal-three-year-ban-all-cricket",
      urlToImage:
        "https://a4.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fi%2Fcricket%2Fcricinfo%2F1099495_800x450.jpg",
      publishedAt: "2020-04-27T11:41:47Z",
      content:
        "Umar Akmal's troubled cricket career has hit its biggest roadblock yet, with the PCB handing him a ban from all representative cricket for three years after he pleaded guilty of failing to report det… [+1506 chars]",
    },
    {
      source: { id: "espn-cric-info", name: "ESPN Cric Info" },
      author: null,
      title:
        "What we learned from watching the 1992 World Cup final in full again | ESPNcricinfo.com",
      description:
        "Wides, lbw calls, swing - plenty of things were different in white-ball cricket back then | ESPNcricinfo.com",
      url: "http://www.espncricinfo.com/story/_/id/28970907/learned-watching-1992-world-cup-final-full-again",
      urlToImage:
        "https://a4.espncdn.com/combiner/i?img=%2Fi%2Fcricket%2Fcricinfo%2F1219926_1296x729.jpg",
      publishedAt: "2020-03-30T15:26:05Z",
      content:
        "Last week, we at ESPNcricinfo did something we have been thinking of doing for eight years now: pretend-live ball-by-ball commentary for a classic cricket match. We knew the result, yes, but we tried… [+6823 chars]",
    },
  ];
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("This is a constructor.");
    this.setState = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container my-3">
        <h2>NewsMonk - Top Headlines</h2>

        <div className="row">
          {this.state.articles.map((element) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-4" key={element.url}>
                <NewsItem
                  title={element.title}
                  description={element.description}
                  imageUrl={element.urlToImage}
                />
              </div>
            );
            console.log(element);
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

Comment: What about moving the articles property outside the class? Create is as a `const`?

Comment: still same error.

Comment: removed the article array outside the class and marked it as const. But still getting same error

Comment: The error means that `this.state` is null, not that `articles` is. That's because the initial state inside the constructor is set using `this.state = { ... }` You have assigned the state to the `this.setState` function instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Initialize state inside the constructor with : `this.state = { ... }`

Just **change**   :

```
this.setState = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false,
    };
```

**to** :

```
this.state = {
      articles: this.articles,
      loading: false,
    };
```